# TFS: Can I have a script run when I create a new label?

Tags: tfs, scripting, label

We're using TFS 2008 for our source control. We're currently doing embedded work so our actual build process is using Analog Devices VisualDSP++ IDE. However, we do still use labels on TFS. What I had hoped was for the ability to have a script run when a label is applied. The idea here is to update version information in some data files. This would help ensure that every label programmatically updated that version string. Currently we have to do this manually.

I'm used to Subversion and Git to some extent and was hunting around for post-commit type hooks or something similar. TFS seems like a different beast.

I'm not a stranger to .NET and (so far as I know) could write a simple app that did the grunt work of updating our files and then applied the label programmatically but it seems like there's got to be an easier way.

Am I right? Is there some mechanism that I can attach a script/batch file when a label is applied in TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, there's no server-side event fired when labels are created/updated.  I'd recommend using branches instead of labels.  Then you can hook the CheckinEvent (filtered by the path of the branch[es] in question).

For more info on subscribing to CheckinEvent (including filters), check out Buck's blog + updates + links: http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2006/09/29/checkinevent-path-filter.aspx

For a code sample that illustrates what your event listener might look like, check out Martin Woodward's "bunny": http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/behind_brian_th.html

For info on using branches instead of labels for code promotion, try http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/

Comment: Cool --  thanks for the additional information and links -- I'd add another point if I could. This is great stuff!